# nth result in Teradata result

Tags: sql, teradata

I'm trying to make a Teradata SQL query that will return the *n*-th chronological visit date for each user.  E.g.,

```
user  |  visit_date
---------------------
  a      1/1      
  b      1/10
  c      1/20
  a      1/3
  a      1/4
  b      1/5
  c      1/15
  b      1/9


> magic_query_for_Second_visit;
user  |  second
------------------
  a       1/3
  b       1/9
  c       1/20
```

I tried something like the below, but Teradata shrieked that "Ordered analytical functions are not allowed in `WHERE` clause."  I've pulled my hair for a while but am not making much progress.  Anyone seen this?

```
select user,
  row_number() over (partition by user order by visit_date desc) as rnum

from visitstable
  where rnum = 2
```

If I exclude the `where` then my result looks promising... I just can't extract what I need!

```
 user |  visit_date | rnum
---------------------------
  a        1/1          1
  a        1/3          2
  a        1/4          3
  b        1/5          1
  b        1/9          2
  b        1/10         3 
  c        1/15         1
  c        1/20         2
```

Thanks in advance for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT 
    user

FROM 
    visitstable

QUALIFY ROW_NUMBER() OVER (
    PARTITION BY 
        user
    ORDER BY 
        visit_date DESC) = 2
```

I see from your comment that you don't necessarily want to rely on the Teradata-specific `QUALIFY`.  The following is a sort-of portable solution (as many RDBMSes are now supporting CTEs) based on another chap's answer:

```
WITH tmp (user, rnum) AS (
    SELECT 
        user, 
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (
            PARTITION BY 
                user 
            ORDER BY 
                visit_date DESC) AS rnum 
    FROM 
        visitstable)
SELECT
    tmp.*
FROM 
    tmp
WHERE 
    tmp.rnum = 2
```

Comment: Thanks, Adam.  TD didn't like the first solution.  The "BY" in `QUALIFY BY ROW_NUMBER()` had to go.

The 2nd one makes my brain sizzle, which is great on a Friday morning.  Thanks!

Comment: Oops, sorry about the `BY` typo. I've now edited that out, thanks. The second example is a temporary table that is made available to your main query. Once I got over the syntax I noticed huge performance gains by simply moving the first step or so of existing queries up into the `WITH` clause. Best of luck to you.

Answer (score 1):

Oh, heaven forbid I should look in the documentation.  FYI, it looks like `qualify` lets you specify ordered analytic constraints.  However, `qualify` isn't ANSI, so I'm still handing out points for a portable solution...

I can do:

```
select user,
  row_number() over (partition by user order by visit_date desc) as rnum

from visitstable
qualify rnum=2
```

...and get...

```
user  |   visit_date  |  rnum
-----------------------------
  a        1/3            2
  b        1/9            2
  c        1/20           2
```

Bookmark it! :)

Answer (score 0):

What version of SQL are you using?  It looks like a later version of MS SQL Server, so try using a "common table expression" like this...

`with cte as (
  select user, 
         row_number() over (partition by user order by visit_date desc) as rnum 
  from visitstable 
)`

select * from cte
where rnum = 2

The syntax might require a little tweaking, but that's the general principal.

Comment: It's Teradata... I'll see if I can translate your suggestion.  Thanks.

Comment: Does your query work, and return the expected row numbers, if you don't have the where clause?  If so, you may be able to insert the results into a temp table, then select the appropriate row numbers out of that.

Comment: Yes, temporary table would probably work portably...  I just wanted to minimize the number of temporary tables, since there are hundreds of millions of records.